# Можно ли в JS/Jquery изменять размер окна браузера?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Можно ли в JS/Jquery изменять размер окна браузера? И как это сделать?

Comment: Насколько я знаю - нельзя. Можно открыть новое окно через скрипт и ему изменять размер, положение и т.д. Можете посмотреть здесь https://learn.javascript.ru/window-methods

Comment: Спасибо большое!